# Custom validation - "blank" directive

Tags: validation, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a validation directive that is pretty much the opposite of `required`. I want to make sure a textarea is cleared before the user can save.

I was able to set the form's `$invalid` flag. I also want to set the `$invalid` flag on the control.

He is what I have so far:

```
application.directive('blank', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var value = elem.val();
            var isBlank = !value || !value.trim();
            ctrl.$setValidity('blank', isBlank);
            return undefined;
        }
    };
});
```

How can I set the control's validity so I can use it for validation, like:

```
$scope.hasBlankError = function (control) {
    return $scope.isSubmitted && control.$error.blank;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your directive is exact opposite of `required` then it's easiest to simply take the `required` directive's source and inverse the logic:

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/bSlAGhKPWvhnkKO7e8kf?p=preview)</kbd>

```js
app.directive('blank', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {

      var validator = function(value) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(value)) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('blank', true);
          return value;
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('blank', false);
          return;
        }
      };

      ctrl.$formatters.push(validator);
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);

      attr.$observe('blank', function() {
        validator(ctrl.$viewValue);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
Password: <input type="text" ng-model="user.password" blank name="password" />
<span ng-show="form.password.$error.blank && form.password.$dirty">Password must be blank</span>
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want. I just wish I knew what this code is doing. I don't know what the `push` and `unshift` operators are doing.

Comment: It would also be useful to have an attribute similar to `ng-required`, so I could conditionally turn on this attribute. I only want it to turn on after the user submits. Could you point me to the location in the angular source control where this functionality is defined?

Comment: This isn't very efficient. The validator function is going to be called 3 times each ng-change - once for $formatters, once for $parsers, and another one for $observe. You should just be pushing it into $parsers.